# How to set wall paper

Tags: mac, keyboard, data-synchronization

I have an iPhone 3G. Recently I am facing a problem with my phone. When I set a wall paper, it is not showing behind the icons. Of course it is showing the picture when my mobile locks. The background behind the icons is plain black. How can I change the wallpaper behind the icons?

Answer (score 2):

In the settings app, there should be an option to change the *lock screen* background,  the *home screen* background, and an option to change *both*. You are likely changing just the lock screen, not the home screen. Try changing the home screen background.

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently update it to iOS 4.2.1? If so, then I'm afraid you're out of luck, as that feature was dropped to help with performance issues. Unless you jailbreak it, you're stuck with the black screen.